# minimize function under constraints

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, solver, minimize

I am looking for a R solver to minimize a function f(x) under the constraint Ax <= B and x >= 0

where A is a matrix, and x and B are vectors.

Do you know one please ?

Thank you !

Comment: Yes thanks, B is also a vector, I corrected it

Comment: have a look to `constrOptim`

Comment: is `f` a linear function? ;-)

Comment: f is a quadratic function :)

Comment: So it is quadratic optimization with linear constraints. https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: I already checked and i found ‘nloptr’ but it allows only the inequalty constraints, hin(x) >= 0
I don't know how to provide the constraint Ax < b

Comment: Only linear terms in x: Ax <= B  <==>  Ax - B <= 0  <==> (-Ax - B) >= 0 <==> B - Ax => 0. Hence, for hin: hin <- function(x) B - Ax ("pseudosyntax").

Comment: @Nik: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please mark it as answered. Otherwise, please give feedback or refine your question to see if someone else can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Since your program is on of quadratic objective function but linear constraints, it's convex. Hence, you shouldn't need to resort to advanced non-linear libraries.

Have a look at the [quadprog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/quadprog.pdf) package. From its documentation, the first example should work as a good template for your

```
## First example from documentation of `quadprog`:
## 
## Assume we want to minimize: -(0 5 0) %*% b + 1/2 b^T b
## under the constraints:      A^T b >= b0
## with b0 = (-8,2,0)^T
## and
##
##
## we can use solve.QP as follows:
##
Dmat       <- matrix(0,3,3)
diag(Dmat) <- 1
dvec       <- c(0,5,0)
Amat       <- matrix(c(-4,-3,0,2,1,0,0,-2,1),3,3)
bvec       <- c(-8,2,0)
solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec=bvec)
```

In this case, the comments describe a program where the `b` vector contains the decision variables. The constraints are on the form `Ax >= b` (A^Tb >= b0), whereas you have constraints of the form `Ax <= b`; the latter is easily transformed into the former with E = -A and f = -b, yielding `Ex >= f`. Note that in this example the coefficient matrix `Dmat` for the quadratic term is the unit matrix, whereas in your case, you'll have to set `Dmat` (and `dvec`) according to your objective function.

To clarify (even further), from the documentation for the `quadprog`program:

> This routine implements the dual method of Goldfarb and Idnani (1982,
>   1983) for solving quadratic programming problems of the form min(−dT b
>   + 1/2bT Db) with the constraints AT b >= b0.

Hence, express your objective function (here using x instead of b for decision variable vector)

```
f(x) = -d^T x + 1/2 x^T D x
where, d: coefficient *vector* for linear part of obj. function
       D: coefficient *matrix* for quadratic
       x: decision variable *vector*
and where ^T denotes the vector transpose.
```

In example above, d and D are denoted dvec and Dmat, respectively.

Comment: I saw that function also but i didn't understand. Does it mean that I have to express my f(x) according to Dmat and dvec such that f(x) = t(dvec).Dmat.dvec ?

Comment: (I'll use x here as decision variable vector). You express your objective function combination of linear form and quadratic form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), i.e., f(x) = dvec * x + x^T * Dmat * x / 2. I'll edit into the answer to clarify.